# No docs avaiable for the "tasksio" library

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have noticed that there no docs for the tasksio library, what I want to learn specifically is the "TaskPool" function, where can I find them?

Comment: What is tasksio? I see a library on PyPI, but it’s only release is version 0.0.0, which I wouldn’t expect to be useable.

Comment: I have seen somebody use it in this code: https://github.com/dropout1337/Twitch-Follow-Abuse/blob/master/main.py

Answer (score 0):

there are no docs for it, but here is what it does:

```
async with tasksio.TaskPool(50) as pool: #the amount of task-workers is 50
   await pool.put(some_async_function(*args))
```

Basically, on the first line, it creates a task pool with 50 workers, then we can do a for loop to run a function multiple times but I did not do that btw. After that, on the 2nd line, we tell the pool you need to run this function and it has these arguments.

Hope this helps.